# Copy the contents of one table into another

Tags: sql, merge

In MSSQL

I have two tables, identical in structure.

Table A is products

Table B is products_update.

On a given day, I get a new product xls in a predefined format. 
I drop the products_update table and use SQL to select into products_update.

In the products table, I want to create new records, and modify existing records, while maintaining older records.

There are (at pressent) 50 columns.. (very little overlap so normalization isn't logical)

Is there an easy bit of SQL to accomplish this.  I see MERGE examples, but I'd have to do the mapping to fields.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure on the question, to create a copy of the existing table, create the new table (table_b) and then run:

```
INSERT INTO table_b SELECT * FROM table_a
```